# How i can find date item in list in C#

Tags: c#

I have DateTime testDate variable.

I have C# List collection which has Date item.
I need to search from list to find if list has any matching item with testDate. Should i use Find or Contains? If date not found than add this date to the list.

I am trying this way

```
        for (var day = fromDate.Date; day.Date <= toDate.Date; day = day.AddDays(1))
        {
            if (!MyList.Find(x => x.Date == day)
                MyList.Add(day, 0);
        }
```

I am getting error at this line. Can not implicitly convert MyList to bool

```
 if (MyList.Find(x => x.Date == day)
```

Comment: Look at the documentation for `Find`. What is the return type? What does your code expect it to be? Also, you have mismatched brackets at the moment... (I'd actually use `Any` from LINQ instead of `Find`, but there's also `Exists`...)

Comment: MyList.Exists(d=>d.Date == day)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
for (var day = fromDate.Date; day.Date <= toDate.Date; day = day.AddDays(1))
{
    if (!MyList.Any(x => x.Date == day))
        MyList.Add(day);
}
```

Comment: MyList.Add(day, 0); says no overload method Add takes 2 argument.

Comment: I have edited the answer, replace MyList.Add(day, 0) with MyList.Add(day)

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you are using the .NET framework's System.Collections.Generic.List, you should have a look at the API docs for the method you are using:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

It's good to get familiar with this documentation.

In your case, the method you are using does not return a bool. It returns the first match and when a match is not found, it will return the default value for the type.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do something like this:

```
var days = Enumerable.Range(0, toDate.Subtract(fromDate).Days + 1)
             .Select(d => fromDate.AddDays(d).Date);

MyList.AddRange(days.Except(MyList.Select(d => d.Date)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
            for (var day = fromDate.Date; day.Date <= toDate.Date; day = day.AddDays(1))
            {
               if (!MyList.Find(day))
                   MyList.Add(day, 0);
            }
```